# scipy.optimize.newton - tolerance argument tol does not refer to the results of the function but to the tolerance of the input?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I wanted to solve a function being close to 0.

I tried using the newton function in the Scipy package, but the tolerance seems to apply to the input and not the function of the input:

```
from scipy.optimise import newton
fn = lambda x: x*x-60
res = newton(fn, 0, tol=0.1, maxiter=10000)
print(res)
print(fn(res))
```

`res` is close to 0, and `fn(res)` is about -60.
It looks like `newton()` stopped because it found two x values which are bounding the solution and within the tolerance.

Is that correct that the tolerance is on `x` and not `fn(x)`?

That seems very counterintuitive to me.

- SciPy reference on `scipy.optimize.newton`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the **tolerance** refers to the **function argument x** of the function f(x).
See here: [zeros.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/optimize/zeros.py#L312)
The code checks if the step from p0 to p is small enough (they call the function argument p and not x in their code), and if yes, the algorithm stops.

You're in fact using the **secant method** and not Newton's method because you did not provide the derivative of your function.
Use `newton(func=lambda x: x*x-60, fprime=lambda x:2*x, x0=0, tol=0.1, maxiter=10000)` instead.

When you run the above code you get an error. That is because you're **starting from a local minimum** of your function where the tangent line is parallel to the x-axis.
In each iteration Newton's method jumps to the position where the tangent line and the x-axis intersect.
This is of course not possible if x-axis and tangent line are parallel. Try **starting** e.g. **from x0=0.1** to get the correct output.
The plot below shows your quadratic function and the tangent lines at x=0 and x=2. It easy to see that starting from x0=2 works because x-axis and tangent will intersect at some point.

[image]